# Triggering timer when ListView item is selected

Tags: qt, listview, timer, qml

I am trying to trigger a timer when an element in a ListView is selected. I am doing this by defining the "running" timer with the code (where  is user defined):

```
running: <containingItem>.ListView.isCurrentItem ? true : false
```

If I don't do this, every element in the list triggers its on timer, so the timer should only go off for the selected listview element. When I do this within the Component of the listview, it works - only the timer associated with the selected item triggers, the rest do not. When I try to do this outside of the ListView (and all containing objects), it doesn't work. I can't seem to call the "ListView.isCurrentItem" command any way I try. What am I missing here?

My code is set up like this:

```
Column {
  id: lv1
  ListView {
    id: lv2
    model: myModel
  }
  Component {
    id: lv3
    Item {
      id: lv4
      Rect {
        Timer {
          id: timer1
          running: (lv4.ListView.isCurrentItem) ? true : false //this works correctly
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Rect {
  Timer {
    id: timer2
    running: (lv1.lv3.lv4.ListView.isCurrentItem ? true : false //this doesn't work correctly
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error: Cannot read property 'lv4' of undefined

Comment: Can you post your actual code? the `error: Cannot read property 'lv4' of undefined` doesn't really make sense here and the `delegate` of the ListView is not set. I see what your error is but can't really explain it clearly without the code

Comment: I assume lv4 is intended to be a delegate for your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.isCurrentItem` is **attached property** and could be referenced only from inside object it is attached to. That is why you couldn't call it from `timer2`.

You can read more about this here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the id of a Component (lv3) as if it is an instance of your delegate. It's just the definition of an object, not an instance of it.

I'm not really clear what your goal is, but if you just need to stop the timer when an item in your list is selected, then you should be able to do this:

```
ListView {
    onCurrentIndexChanged: timer2.stop()
}
```